# Problema con una API usando método GET en Postman

Tags: nodejs, api, express, postman, http-get

**¡Buen día!** Estoy creando mi primera API para un proyecto. Sin embargo, tengo algunas dudas sobre el funcionamiento de como realizar consultas y crear nueva información usando una base de datos SQL.

Al instalar SQL, me encontré con que me solicitó usar el puerto 3306 y al momento de crear la API utilizo el puerto 3050 ya que no me permite ejecutar el servidor con nodemon si utilizo el mismo puerto de SQL. Me da la sensación que al tener la API y a SQL en puertos distintos es el motivo por el que me salta este error al momento de generar la consulta para devolver los usuarios que tenga. No estoy muy seguro si es éste el error, pero es lo que me viene a la mente y no sé cómo solucionarlo llevo muy poco tiempo programando y este sería mi primer proyecto.

Adjunto primero el error que me da al hacer la consulta por los usuarios a través de Postman:

```
GET http://localhost:3050/users
Error: "read ECONNRESET"
Request "Headers"
User-Agent: "PostmanRuntime/7.26.10"
Accept: "*/*"
Postman-Token: "14dfc80a-e578-4bac-9849-c5084b8b2da5"
Host: "localhost:3050"
Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate, br"
Connection: "keep-alive"
```

Adjunto el código que tengo hasta ahora para ver si me pueden ayudar por si está relacionado al código...

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const { request } = require('express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3050;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// MySQL
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '****',
    database: 'node_budget_mysql'
});

// Route
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Welcome to my API');
});

// All clients
app.get ('/users', (request, response) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM users'

    connection.query(sql, (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        if (results.lenght >0) {
            res.json(results);
        } else {
            res.send('There are no results for your search');
        };
    });
});

// Check connect
connection.connect(error => { 
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('The server Database is running!');
});

app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

**¡Muchas gracias por su tiempo y cualquier aporte será bien recibido!**

Comment: Los puertos no tienen nada que ver con tu problema.. el puerto es como la "direccion de tu casa".. cada app necesita un puerto distinto.. si no, lo que llega no sabe donde tocar...

Comment: Este problema se solucionó para mí eliminando los caracteres basura de la entrada de variables GraphQl. Tenía caracteres basura en la entrada de variables GraphQl que no eran visibles, pero en otro editor eran visibles, podrías intentar por ahí

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, voy a probar con eso! Estoy actualizando cualquier cosa. ¡¡Buen día!!

Comment: Excelente metáfora... ¡Me dejó bastante clara esa duda que tenía!

Answer (score 0):

¡Pude encontrar el problema!

```
// All clients
app.get ('/users', (**request, response**) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM users'

    connection.query(sql, (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        if (results.lenght >0) {
            **res**.json(results);
        } else {
            **res**.send('There are no results for your search');
        };
    });
});
```

El problema venía porque definí de forma distinta los parámetros... Definí la respuesta como response y luego lo coloqué como res... cómo se nota que aún estoy muy nuevito. Gracias por la respuesta en relación a los puertos.

Comment: Que bueno que solucionaste tu problema, te recomiendo marques tu respuesta como aceptada asi tu pregunta ya deja de figurar como no resuelta